# Rotating around Z axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and C#, I have been trying to make the object tilt to the right or left when it is moving
but what I have is that the object is rotating in a full circle around the Z axis.

that's what I got, I had it from the unity documentation.

```
    [SerializeField] private float _moveSpeed = 50f;
    [SerializeField] private float _turnSpeed = 3f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 100.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
     
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.position += Time.deltaTime * _moveSpeed * transform.right;

            float translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * _moveSpeed;

            float rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
            translation *= Time.deltaTime;
            rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Translate(0, 0, translation);

            transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotation);


        }
```

that's what I got, I had it from the unity documentation.

Comment: It is unlcear what your problem is. Tilting is rotation around Z, do you want to limit that rotation?

Comment: You can check out `Mathf.PingPong`. This method rotates the object from point A to point B and back to point A. [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question has been answered many times. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unity+rotate